# getting concurrent request from client in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, http, file-handling

I am trying to create a server using **Node.js HTTP Module** where a server gets concurrent request from client as a JSON data, stores it into a JSON file and then reads it back from the file and sends it as a response to the client.

I have progress as you can see my below code.

**Question**

1) In my code i'm closing the opened file.. here, the "file closed successfully" log comes at first and then the "Saved" log message. *fs.open created fd and one thread while handling fs.writeFile other executed fs.close*  **How to code it in correct manner ?**

2)How to make a client make concurrent http request to the server i have created here.. *I don't wanna use Express*. I am trying to learn basics first.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var body = '';

    request.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
    });

    request.on('socket', function (){ 
        var start = new Date(); 
            console.log(start);
    });

    request.on('end',function(){
        var clientData = body;

        fs.open('jsonData.json', 'r+', function(err, fd) {
            if(err){
                    fs.writeFileSync('jsonData.json', clientData+"\n",  function(err) {
                        if(err){return console.error(err);}
                        console.log("file created...!!\n");

                    });
            }
            else{
                //append data

                fs.appendFile('jsonData.json', clientData+"\n", function (err) {
                    if (err) {return console.error(err);}
                    console.log('Saved!');

                });

                if(fd>=1){
                    fs.close(fd, function(err){
                        if (err){
                            console.log(err);
                        } 
                        console.log("File closed successfully.");
                    });
                }
            }

        });

        //open and read to send response


        response.writeHead(200, 'OK', {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end('Data received.');
    });


}).listen(8080,'127.0.0.1',function(){
    console.log("listening to server at http://localhost:8080");
});
```

Comment: use syncronisation :)

Comment: You need to call `fs.close()` inside the `fs.appendFile()` callback.  The way you have it now, you are closing the file before the `fs.appendFile()` has completed.  You also need proper error handling in about a dozen places.

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh can i know where and how ?

Comment: @jfriend00 then do i have to write two fs.close ?  one inside fs.writeFile another inside fs.appendFile

Comment: Well, when you do all the proper error handling, you'll need even more than two.  I'd rewrite this using promises for all async operations and then you can handle errors, completion and sequencing a lot simpler.